# como Preencher um DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Alguém poderia me ajudar como faço para preencher um `DropDownListFor`?

Antes estava fazendo dessa forma:

```
@Html.DropDownList("lstAffiliate", string.Empty);
```

Mas vi que não era recomendado, ai decidi fazer com o `ListFor`.

Tenho o meu *controller* onde recebo a lista pronta e repasso para a `PartialView`:

```
public ActionResult ComboAffiliate()
{
    FilterAffiliate Affiliate = new FilterAffiliate();
    List<SelectListItem> model = Affiliate.filterAffiliate();

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

para esta Partial

```
@model  IBS_WEB.Models.Filters.FilterAffiliate

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CD_AFFILIATE, Model.?, new { @class ="ComboWidth" })
```

Como eu faço para listar nesse `DropDownListFor`?

Answer (score 4):

Olá,

Basicamente para a criação de um DropDownListFor você vai precisar declarar os parâmetros abaixo

@Html.DropDownListFor(, )

Model:

```
public class Veiculo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }            
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public int idModeloVeiculo { get; set; }
}

public class ModeloVeiculo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }    
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

Action MVC :

```
[Controller]
ViewData["idModeloVeiculo"] = new SelectList(contexto.ModeloVeiculos.toList(),"ID","Descricao");
```

HTML :

```
@model Veiculo

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.idModeloVeiculo , null)
```

Conforme podemos ver a View é fortemente tipada para a classe "Veiculo" que possui o atributo "idModeloVeiculo" do tipo inteiro. No momento que criamos uma ViewData na controller com o mesmo nome do atributo :

```
[Controller]
ViewData["idModeloVeiculo"] = new SelectList(contexto.ModeloVeiculos.toList(),"ID","Descricao");
```

Automaticamente o .Net verifica que será utilizada a ViewData "idModeloVeiculo"

```
//Na verdade "m.idModeloVeiculo" é ViewData "idModeloVeiculo"
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.idModeloVeiculo , null)
```

Então altere seu código da seguinte forma :

```
public ActionResult ComboAffiliate()
    {
        FilterAffiliate Affiliate = new FilterAffiliate();
        List<SelectListItem> model = Affiliate.filterAffiliate();

ViewData["Combo"] = new SelectList(Affiliate.filterAffiliate().ToList(),"ID","Descricao");
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Partial :

```
@model  IBS_WEB.Models.Filters.FilterAffiliate

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CD_AFFILIATE, ViewData["Combo"] ,new { @class ="ComboWidth" })
```

Segue links.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057873/how-to-write-a-simple-html-dropdownlistfor

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142961/mvc3-dropdownlistfor-a-simple-example

Answer (score 3):

Em `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CD_AFFILIATE, Model.?, new { @class ="ComboWidth" })` você quer preencher o `Model.?` com `new SelectList()`.

Ou seja precisa dizer ao helper da dropdown como será montada a lista de seleção, usando o new SelectList.

Ex:

```
 @Html.DropDownList(
    "Teste", 
    new SelectList(
        Model.Select(x => new { Value = x.CD_AFFILIATE, Text = x.SuaPropriedadeDeTexto}),
        "Value",
        "Text"
    )
)
```

Mas tenho a impressão que você será mais feliz, criando uma classe ViewModel com uma propriedade para guardar ou setar o Id selecionado na DropDown, e outra propriedade contendo o retorno de `Affiliate.filterAffiliate()`

Veja um exemplo que criei no .NET Fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/GQbcvs que pode lhe ser útil.

Comment: vou dar uma olhada aqui. vlw

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class TipoVeiculo {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }

    public class Veiculo {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public int TipoVeiculoId { get; set; }
        public virtual TipoVeiculo { get; set; }
    }

    // No Controller 
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        var tipos = new List<TipoVeiculo>{ new TipoVeiculo{ id = 1, Nome = "Moto", new TipoVeiculo{ id = 2, Nome = "Carro"} };
        ViewBag.Tipos = tipos;
        return View();
    } 

    // Na View
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
    f => f.TipoVeiculoId,/*Qual atributo,*/
    new SelectList(
    ViewBag.Tipos,/*(fonte de dado,*/
    "Id",/*(Quem vai aparecer o campo value,*/
    "Nome"),/*quem vai aparecer de text),*/
    new { @class = "form-control" })/*atributos do select html*/

    // resumindo fica assim

    @Html.DropDownListFor(f => f.TipoVeiculoId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Tipos, "Id","Nome"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```